# How to click this button using Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
 <div class="mdl-align"> == $0
    : :before
    <button class="fp-upload-btn btn-primary btn">Upload this file</button> == $0
    : :after
 </div>
```

The above codes are from a website, however I am unable to click this button despite trying multiple attempts. Im using selenium with C# to do an automation testing.
What this button does, is to simply submit a form.

Comment: I'd recommend setting the `id` attribute on all components you want to manipulate using Selenium or any other UI Automation framework. Like @jainish kapadia said you can use XPath or CssSelectors like in jQuery but these rely on the layout, styling or even the language of the page. By setting the ID you don't have to worry about these variations provided the ids stay the same (the UI could be completely changed and it should still work.) Of course if you're crawling a page you don't own then XPath and CssSelectors are the best way I'm aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `xpath` locator to click on `Upload this file button`.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Upload this file')]")).Click();
```

Comment: Hi, just saw your comment, I've tried and it works, may i know how you actually understand it? I'm very new in this

Comment: Your button is contains text as `Upload this file` So, Start your `xpath` with `button` tag and then use` text` method for find the element.

Comment: Fore more details on xpath, refer this link, https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: @JainishKapadia can you please check this too.Thank u so much .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044226/selenium-webdriver-not-working-correctly-on-button-click-events-what-is-the-iss