# Selenium WebDriver not working correctly on button click events. What is the issue here?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using following code to scrape data from a website. I have following interface
[image]

Here is the HTML

```html
<div id="es-content" class="es-content">
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="searchTrain.action" method="post" id="search_form_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedLocale" value="en" id="selectedLocaleId" />
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
          <label class="control-label" for="startStation">
                                <strong>Start Station:&nbsp;<font color="red">*</font></strong>
                            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="control-group" id="startStationDiv">

            <select name="searchCriteria.startStationID" id="startStation" class="es-select">
              <option value="-1">--- Select ---</option>
              <option value="3">Item1</option>
              <option value="410">Item2</option>
              <option value="13">Item3</option>
              <option value="11">Item4</option>
            </select>
            <span class="help-inline" id="startStationErrorSpan" style="display: none;"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
          <label class="control-label" for="endStation">
                                <strong>End Station:&nbsp;<font color="red">*</font></strong>
                            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="control-group" id="endStationDiv">

            <select name="searchCriteria.endStationID" id="endStation" class="es-select">
              <option value="-1">--- Select ---</option>
              <option value="3">Item1</option>
              <option value="410">Item2</option>
              <option value="13">Item3</option>
              <option value="11">Item4</option>
            </select>
            <span class="help-inline" id="endStationErrorSpan" style="display: none;"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="button" class="es-button" onclick="formSubmit();"><span>Search</span></button>
          <button type="button" class="es-button" onclick="resetPage();"><span>Reset</span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to automatically select Start dropdown menu , then the End dropdown then want to click the Search button. For this I wrote following code

```
// Set up the Selenium WebDriver
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless"); // Run Chrome in headless mode (no UI)
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Load the URL
string url = "MY URL GOES HERE";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

// Automatically select the Start Station dropdown
IWebElement startStationDropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("startStation"));
startStationDropdown.Click();

// Simulate selecting an option (e.g., the second option)
IWebElement selectedOption = startStationDropdown.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@value='159']"));
selectedOption.Click();

IWebElement endStationDropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("endStation"));
endStationDropdown.Click();

// Simulate selecting an option (e.g., the second option)
IWebElement selectedOptionEndStation = startStationDropdown.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@value='46']"));
selectedOptionEndStation.Click();


// Click the "Search" button
IWebElement searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@class='es-button'])[1]"));
searchButton.Click();

 // Now, you can use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the updated HTML
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
```

after clicking the Search button from the same page there will be a result which comes with a Back button. Search controls will be dissappear. Only back button and result table. I need to get there.
But when I debug the htmlDocument's captured DOM, The same page was there. No result page. Means no click event fired. On every object elements are loading correctly. When I debug I can see the correct button text on each element. What is the issue here?

Also I insert below code before loadhtml. Because when user press search it shows the result with a back button on the top. Here is the HTML for that button.

```
<button type="button" class="es-button" onclick="window.history.go(-1);">
  <span>Back</span>
</button>
```

So when the back button comes it means result is ready and that's the result I want to capture. Result is a table. I can scrape it.
Below is a code that I use to wait until that back button appear.
But nothing works.

```
        // Use an explicit wait to wait for the result element to become available
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
    var element = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("button[onclick*='window.history.go(-1)']")));
```

There are no antiscrape mechanism installed on this site.

Comment: first of all i would suggest pasting the HTML portion of the form so everyone might get a better idea of the issue. Also the page might not be loaded yet when you "LoadHtml"

Comment: Without resource it's hard to say, what happened, but it looks like you should wait for output to be visible. And if you want to repeat - probably you should wait for staleness of previous output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to wait until `es-content` container is re-rendered after clicking on Search button and wait for it's visibility again.

That would be a sign that result table is appeared.

You just init container element on search and after click you wait for `StalenessOf`.

Btw, for me your dropdowns are native dropdowns, so I used `Select`.

```bash
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        IWebElement startStationDropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("startStation"));

        SelectElement selectStartStation = new SelectElement(startStationDropdown);
        selectStartStation.SelectByValue("159");

        IWebElement endStationDropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("endStation"));

        SelectElement selectEndStation = new SelectElement(endStationDropdown);
        selectEndStation.SelectByValue("46");

        IWebElement esContent = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("es-content"));

        IWebElement searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@class='es-button'])[1]"));
        searchButton.Click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(esContent));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("es-content")));

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
```

Comment: Hi yaroslavm the search button will be not appear again. After search back button and result will be appear.

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage does my code work?

Comment: Nope, OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 10 seconds'..Exception occur at wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(esContent));

Comment: Sorry mr Yaroslavm.. Its worked....its really working......I just inserted your select tags and put the es-content on right place..nothing was changed. exactly as you described. Previous it was my mistake..Can you please explain what did I do wrong? What is stanlesof commmand?

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage Well, for sure you got Html source too early.
When you wait for back button visibility and it didn't work for you, I have assumption that Back button was rendered before the table was rendered as far as rendering button is not guarantee that you got search output, it can be in `rendering` state. 
By waiting app container is not rendered (staleness) and then waiting for new app container to be rendered you guarantee that results are rendered and present in DOM

Comment: Thank you. Do we need to wait 10 seconds everytime? Once the dom is loaded can we do our next action.. I am talking about TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).. Do we really nessary this?

Comment: It doesn't wait 10 seconds, thats explicit wait. It waits no more then 10 seconds. By default AFAIK it re-checks element state every 250 ms.

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/webdriverwait-in-selenium-c-sharp/